# Java Assertion in Try with multiple catchs

Tags: java, exception, assert, assertions

**Scenario:**

```
class Assert {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        try {
            assert false;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re) {
            System.out.println("In the handler of RuntimeException");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("In the handler of Exception");
        }
        catch (Error ae) {
            System.out.println("In the handler of Error");
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("In the handler of Throwable");
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting 'In the handler of Error' because AssertionError is subclass of Error but it doesn't show anything and terminate normal. after then to check the out put I added this one catch handler before Error handler .

```
catch (AssertionError t) {
    System.out.println("In the handler of Throwable");
}
```

in know it's not a good practice to catch Error but if we does not need to catch why the program was not crashed it terminate normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default assertions are disabled, add `-ea`  in the command line when you execute your code with `java`:

```
java -ea Assert
```